# Is there a way to pass an object instance from MATLAB to Simulink?

Tags: matlab, oop, simulink

I have created a class 'BinaryTree' in Matlab. I would like to pass an instance of this object to Simulink, and use the associated class methods in Simulink. For example, I would like to pass a function in the format of 'Binarytree' class to Simulink and iteratively evaluate this function using 'ComputeTree', which is a method defined in the 'BinaryTree' class, using the simulation values.

I have considered using [Matlab System Objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/system-objects.html). I was wondering if there are better-suited ways to meet my objective, or if there are any available examples using Matlab System Objects to do what is described above.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the Matlab Function block from the [library](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html)

You don't need to pass anything, you can use persistent memory if you need to keep track of previous values.